# Access and modify child items of Button in UWP C++/CX app at runtime

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

I'm pretty new to UWP Xaml C++/CX development so I apologize if I use the wrong terms.

I'm trying to make an image/photo thumbnail selection tray. The user is to select which folder to browse and the contents are displayed in the scrollable thumbnail tray with the filename displayed below.

Pages are built in xaml and i'm using C++/CX. The thumbnail tray is built using the following xaml

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,20,20,20" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Grid x:Name="thumb_grid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I dynamically add new rows via code using

```
AddRow() {
   RowDefinition^ rd = ref new RowDefinition();
   rd->Height.Auto;
   thumb_grid->RowDefinitions->Append(rd);
}
```

Then I populate each grid element with a new Button using

```
AddImageButton(int row, int col) {
   Button^ b = ref new Button();

   auto style = R->Lookup("ButtonStyle1");
   b->Style = safe_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Style^>(style);

   thumb_grid->Children->Append(b);
   thumb_grid->SetRow(b, row);
   thumb_grid->SetColumn(b, col);
}
```

Where "ButtonStyle1" is defined in my dictionary.xaml as

```
   <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <!--REMOVED THIS SECTION TO REDUCE EXAMPLE CODE-->

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                    <Image x:Name="thumb_image" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Assets/demo.jpg"/>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="thumb_filename" Grid.Row="1" Text="demo.jpg" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            TextAlignment="Center"/>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

All this results in creating the desired output as shown in the following image. Obviously I'm just using a hardcoded image and text for the Button content at the moment.

[image: Thumbviewer sample]

**The Problem**
The question is how do I dynamically change the content of the custom image buttons?

Currently I can change the images within a button by accessing the content by name. However this requires the image content of a button have a unique name.

Xaml code

```
<Button x:Name="btnToggleShowHide" Grid.Row="1"  Height="50" Width="50" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            Background="Transparent"
            Click="btnToggleShowHide_Click">
    <Image x:Name="imgToggleShowHideBtn"  
        Source="Assets/Graphics/show.png"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Button>
```

and the C++/CX code for changing the image (excluding the actually logic, just showing the code used)

```
show = ref new BitmapImage(ref new Uri(imgToggleShowHideBtn->BaseUri->RawUri, "Assets/Graphics/show.png"));
hide = ref new BitmapImage(ref new Uri(imgToggleShowHideBtn->BaseUri->RawUri, "Assets/Graphics/hide.png"));

imgToggleShowHideBtn->Source = show;
imgToggleShowHideBtn->Source = hide;
```

But I cannot directly access the text within the custom button image "demo.jpg" by using its name

```
thumb_filename->Text = "test.jpg";
```

because the textblock thumb_filename only exists at runtime. In AddImageButton() I need to somehow set the content but can't figure out how to access the child objects in the button. In my mind I want to do something like

```
Button^ b = ref new Button();
auto style = R->Lookup("ButtonStyle1");
b->Style = safe_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Style^>(style);

//NOT ACTUAL CODE - THIS IS WHAT I'M TRYIN TO ACHIEVE
b->Image->Source = img;        //obviously wont work because it has no knowledge whether ButtonStyle1 contains an image
b->TextBlock->Text = filename; //obviously wont work because it has no knowledge whether ButtonStyle1 contains a textblock
```

Comment: I suggest you could replace the custom button with [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview) . And you could dynamically change the content of GridView by modify the `ViewModel` .

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate using GridView. Do you have any good reference examples for using them?

Comment: Absolutely, you could reference this [official code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView). Please check.

Comment: Thanks, I've already downloaded all those and have been using them to learn up to this point. The only problem is the lack of C++ based examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using the approach suggested by [Nico Zhu - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254781/nico-zhu-msft) and using GridView with data binding.

Firstly I created a button class (Note: I'm still in the process of refining so there may be some redundant snippets)

```
namespace Models {

    [Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
    public ref class FileBrowser sealed
    {

    private:
        Platform::String^ _fname;
        Platform::String^ _path;
        ImageSource^ _thumbImage;
        BitmapImage^ _imagedata;

    public:
        FileBrowser();

        property Platform::String^ Filename
        {
            Platform::String^ get()
            {
                return _fname;
            }
            void set(Platform::String^ value)
            {
                _fname = value;
            }
        }

        property Platform::String^ Filepath
        {
            Platform::String^ get()
            {
                return _path;
            }
            void set(Platform::String^ value)
            {
                _path = value;
            }
        }

        property ImageSource^ ThumbImage
        {
            ImageSource^ get()
            {
                return _thumbImage;
            }
            void set(ImageSource^ value)
            {
                _thumbImage = value;
            }
        }

        property BitmapImage^ ImageData
        {
            BitmapImage^ get()
            {
                return _imagedata;
            }
            void set(BitmapImage^ value)
            {
                _imagedata = value;
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Add #include "FileBrowser.h" to the "MainPage.xaml.h". In my View.xaml page that contains the image browser/list add xmlns:local="using:Models" to the  tag.

My GridView is created in the following way

```
<GridView x:Name="thumb_grid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,20,20,20" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemClick="thumb_grid_ItemClick">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MaxHeight="200" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="200">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Row="0"  Source="{Binding ImageData}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Filename}" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="20" Foreground="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.Items>

            </GridView.Items>
        </GridView>
```

At runtime a new button is added to the GridView using (where f and I supply the relevant file and image data)

```
auto btn = ref new Models::FileBrowser();
btn->Filename = f->GetAt(i)->DisplayName + f->GetAt(i)->FileType;
btn->Filepath = f->GetAt(i)->Path;
btn->ImageData = I;
thumb_grid->Items->Append(btn);
```

[image: Images loaded at runtime]

This now results in the desired image tray that displays the contents of a folder. Each image clickable/touchable and calls the same function, in this case each item in the GridView calls thumb_grid_ItemClick() when pressed.

Data from the button can be obtained using the following

```
void View::thumb_grid_ItemClick(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemClickEventArgs^ e)
{
    auto btn = (Models::FileBrowser^)e->ClickedItem;
}
```